# Is there a way in Visual Studio and TFS to view items checked out to local workspaces?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I understand that TFS Local Workspaces are designed to help users work more seamlessly when not connected to the TFS server; however, unlike when using Server Workspaces, I cannot see the status of a file from Visual Studio Source Control Explorer. Our team is connected to the TFS Server 90% of the time. It seems that Local Workspaces should be able to communicate file checked-out status back to the TFS Server when connected. As a team manager I would like to know what files team members currently have checked out in several scenarios, while still retaining the flexibility offered by Local Workspaces.

1. I want to know how often team members are checking in their code (or not).
2. I want to know if someone is already working on a file before checking it out as well.
3. I want to handle a lost/broken laptop scenario by knowing which files had un-checked-in changes.

Is there a way to do this with Visual Studio Source Control Explorer or another tool?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the items checked out will display automatically when you navigate to the specific items in `Source Control Explorer`. Reference below screenshot.

> 1. I want to know how often team members are checking in their code (or
>      not).

You just need to check the changesets history.

> 2. I want to know if someone is already working on a file before checking it out as well.

Just navigate to the specific items in `Source Control Explorer` as I mentioned above, it will shown the status in `Pending Change` column.

> 3. I want to handle a lost/broken laptop scenario by knowing which files had un-checked-in changes.

Generally the files with status displayed under `Pending Change` column are the files which have un-checked-in changes.

**However** there is a tool called [**Team Foundation Sidekicks**](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) which is a suite of tools ( `includes Code Review Sidekick, Shelveset Sidekick, Labels Sidekick, History Sidekick, Workspace Sidekick and Status`) for TFS administrators and advanced users providing rich GUI for administrative and advanced version control tasks, you can use it to check and track the things you required. (Unfortunately it's no available for VS 2017, the latest version 6.0 only works for VS 2015)

[image]

Comment: @gotorg Is that answered your question? have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: I would expect to see what you're describing, but all files show a blank Pending Change value. Is it possible this needs to be turned on somewhere?

Comment: @gotorg A blank Pending Change value means no anyone check it out, you can select a file and `check out for edit` with one user , then check the file with another user or the same user on another machine in source control explorer, now you will see the values...

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Our team sees the Pending Change and User columns filled with blank values. We are using VS2015, TFS2015, with Local Workspaces. It seems there must be some setting I am missing.